# KafkaAvroDeserializer - NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/common/config/ConfigException

Tags: java, exception, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, confluent-platform

I am using spark for get data from a topic kafka. I must deserialaizer avro data with KafkaAvroDeserialaizer. I config kafka consumer so:

```
 kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.0.4.215:9092");
 kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
 kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer",io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
 // kafkaParams.put("key.convert", com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.source.JsonSimpleConverter.class);
 //kafkaParams.put("value.convert",com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.source.JsonSimpleConverter.class);
 kafkaParams.put("group.id", "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream");
 kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
 kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
```

But when i execute the code i have this exception Exception in thread

> "streaming-start" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   io/confluent/common/config/ConfigException

Can someone tell me where i can find this class def? For example maven dependency ext.

Comment: Can you share the whole stack trace? Also the code snippet is too limited. What type `kafkaParams`? How do you use `kafkaParams`?

Comment: Did you set the correct dependencies and the confluent repo

Answer (score 1):

You need the following dependency:
group: 'io.confluent', name: 'common-config', version: yourConfluentVersion

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I used `5.1.0` confluent platform version. I checked [compatibility `kafka <-> confluent`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#cp-and-apache-kafka-compatibility) and found that there are newer version in the same level of compatibility. I updated version up to `5.1.1` and it resolve that issue for me.

As an example:

[image]